# Is it possible to compare "North, South, East" and "North, East, South" and find equivalence?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-5.0

Is it possible to compare two strings such as:

```
"North, South, East" == "North, East, South"
```

and find equivalence, based on the fact that

```
both contain "North"
```

or

```
both contain "South"
```

Another example

```
"North" == "North, South"
```

Also

```
"North" != "South"
```

Obviously the comma seperates the key strings for comparison. Not sure if there is a key function in C# that could help with this? "Contains" will not work, as the order of the delimited values could be different, ie

```
"North, South" == "South, North"
```

Any help with this would be gratefully accepted. Looking for some expert C# guidance!

Comment: Split the strings and compare each of them.

Comment: Split the strings into arrays using .Split(",".ToCharArray()) and then use Intersection to see what exists in both.

Comment: Thanks for replying. It is because "North, South" contains "North"

Comment: Yes it is possible :)

Comment: Please repose this question to make it clearer. Being able to specify requirements becomes more and more important as your career progresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `String.Split` to get a `string[]` from the `String` where each token is separated by a delimiter, for example the comma:

```
var tokens1 = "North, South, East".Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim());
var tokens2 = "North, East, South".Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim());
```

I have used `Enumerable.Select` to remove leading or trailing spaces with `String.Trim`. Now you can use `Intersect` + `Any` to check if there's a common intersection:

```
bool anyIntersection = tokens1.Intersect(tokens2).Any();
```

Comment: Did you note OP says `"North == "North, South"` ? Not sure why though.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, because "North, South" contains "North". Similarly "South, North" == "North, East" for the same reason, but one could not use "contains" to test this equivalence.

Comment: @SamJolly So if any of these match you need to return true?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: i thought that it just means that a single string `North` also intersects with `"North, South"`. Thats how `String.Split` works. Even a single string will create a `String[]` with that single string.

Answer (score 1):

You can write it using `Any()` this way:

```
string NEWS = "North, South, East";
string NEW = "North, East, South";

var temp1 = NEWS.Split(',');
var temp2 = NEW.Split(',');

if (temp1.Any(x => temp2.Contains(x)))
{
 // means equal
}
```

Comment: This is interesting as the value is originating from a DB via LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this, which prints "Strings in common: South, East"

```
string s1 = "North, South, East";
string s2 = "East, West, South";

var strings1 = s1.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim());
var strings2 = s2.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim());

var stringsInCommon = strings1.Intersect(strings2);

Console.WriteLine("Strings in common: " + string.Join(", ", stringsInCommon));
```